# Vector vs. ArrayList which is better?

Tags: java, vector, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated)

Which type is better to use and how to choice right type (memory usage, execution...)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated) `Vector` is considered "obsolete", use `ArrayList` instead.

Answer (score 51):

You should normally use `ArrayList` - it offers better performance.

`Vector` has just one "advantage" - it is synchronised for concurrent modification. But it turns out in practice that this feature isn't very useful because `Vector` synchronises at the level of each individual operation. If you are writing concurrent code, you typically need to lock at a much higher level of granularity than an individual collection class.

As a result, `Vector` is often considered deprecated nowadays.